# Flutter apps not running on any editor

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to run an app in flutter but it keeps showing me this error. Same case with all the other apps in other editors like vs code and Intellij Idea. I don't know how it came up. It just popped out of the blue.

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Running "flutter pub get" in basic_login_app...
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
pub get failed (1; The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Flutter SDK to environment variables?

Run "which flutter"

Run "flutter doctor"

Running "flutter pub get" is if you are using a flutter package and you want to include it in your project.
Have you included it in your *pubspec.yaml* file?

Comment: all packages that i use are already in the pubspec file. also ran "which flutter" and "flutter doctor". Everything seemed ok.